# How to restart current node without failing the test in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to restart my linux server before preforming some tests on it in my Jenkins job.
I want to restart it and wait a while and then start to run some tests.
but the restart keep failing my node (and my run)
Iv used "shutdown" instead of "reboot" but if posable I wish to use "reboot"

```
node(my_server)
{
    stage("restart server"){
        try{
            sh 'sudo shutdown -r now -m ${!my_server}'
        }
        catch (Exception e) {sleep 180}
     }
}
```